# Angular 4 - refresh list of second select form after selecting the first select form

Tags: angular, function, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing

I have two `select form` in one form tag with option value of second one is referring to the first one.

Currently, I designed this in a template-driven form and I have `(change)` attribute implemented in the first `select form`.

Basically, the first `select form` has the selection of id as its option values and then it will be passed as a parameter so the second `select form` can fetch its option value based on the id.

The function didn't throw any error however it didn't load the value into the dropdown list.

What is the workaround?

EDIT: Here is the json model:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "bookA",
        "authors": [
            "authorA",
            "authorB"
        ]
},
 {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "bookB",
        "authors": [
            "authorA",
            "authorB",
            "authorC"
        ]
},
```

I want to have the first `select form` to load the title and then the second `select form` to load the corresponding authors.

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

Without code, this would be hard to help.

But if you want an easy solution, here it is :

```
options = [
  { option: 'Option 1', value: 'opt1', subOptions: [
    { option: 'Option 1-1', value: 'opt1-1' }
  ]},
  { option: 'Option 2', value: 'opt2', subOptions: [
    { option: 'Option 2-1', value: 'opt2-1' }
  ]},
];
```

In your HTML :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="select1">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option.option}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="select2" *ngIf="select1">
  <option *ngFor="let option of select1.subOptions" [value]="option">{{option.option}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you. I have added the json model for further explaining what I intended to achieve. It would be nice if I can get an example based on it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried your example before however the second select form does not load any values. And console also does not show any error.

Comment: @trichetriche This solution does not appear to achieve what the author is looking for. As per the question, the value of the first select should be set to `option.id` (number). In your code, it gets set to `option` (object). While this allows you to easily get the values for the second select, it means the value of the first select is now an object instead of a number.